# Least Recently Used vs Second Chance algorithm

Tags: c++, caching, lru, page-replacement

Is it normal for Second Chance algorithm to have more page replacements than the least recently used algorithm supposing we had a counter for each algorithm??

Comment: Have you coded these algorithms and see this behavior? [Edit] that code into the question.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i have used these page replacement algorithms in some of my work but this doesn't have to do with the question. I was asking incase there was an definite answer to this like "yes, you get more page faults with lru than second chance" and vice versa

Comment: It is a pseudo-LRU policy, so the hit rate can be better or worse but will be very similar. I have never observed a significant difference in workloads when conducting an in-depth analysis of policies. For example an MRU biased workload (loopy) is the worst case for LRU, but a pseudo-LRU can do slightly better by being less strict (e.g. sampled LRU). However that will only offer a gain of 1% or less, since it still makes very similar decisions.